# Elk stack, why I can't create index of rabbitmq messages?

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I recently developed a C# web app that produce and consume messages on a RabbitMQ exchange of topic type, everything is working very good. Than I decided to use the ELK stack to analyze the RabbitMQ logs and it also working very good as expected, than my troubles starts when I decided to try to log all the messages that are produced and consumed.
I followed this guide to deploy the ELK stack.

[How to Install ELK Stack on Debian 9](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-the-elk-stack-on-debian-9/)

Than my trouble started..
this is an extract of the `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'`

```
{
  "name" : "dvv7m8h",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "545-XOzEQ7W2C982ISVnng",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.8.4",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "bca0c8d",
    "build_date" : "2019-10-16T06:19:49.319352Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.7.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

and as the official documentation states (
[Rabbitmq input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.8/plugins-inputs-rabbitmq.html)) I need to enable the plugin by running this command `bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-rabbitmq`, but **there is no bin/logstash-plugin command available for me**! I tried to look nearly everywhere on the world wide web but after three days still no results. As reference I'll post my logstash config file as well.

```
input {
   rabbitmq {
                host => 'xxx.yyy.zz.nn:5672'
                exchange => "my_exchange"
                exchange_type => "topic"
                id => "rabb"
                }

        }
}
output {
      elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
      index => "rabtest-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
   }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Is the plugin already shipped as a bundle inside logstash v.6.8.x? Why I don't have there forementioned command to install the plugin? Thanks.

Comment: How did you install Logstash — download the .tar.gz, DEP or RPM,...?

Comment: From which directory did you tried to run `logstash-plugin`? If you installed using the tutorial you linked, you used the `.deb.` packages and then the binaries are [located](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.8/dir-layout.html) in `/usr/share/logstash/`

Comment: @leandrojmp thanks a lot...I forgot that..if you put this comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct solution